# How to find the release date of a Maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I'm getting a list of maven dependencies from my java app and I would like to know when each package was released.

Currently I'm checking the metadata info (`https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/$groupURL/$artifactID/maven-metadata.xml`), but I'm not sure what those dates in that file means. I was wondering if `lastUpdated` would be the correct field.

I'm open for more ideas. Thank you.

Comment: If you know the GAV you can check https://central.sonatype.com/

Comment: oh. nice! @khmarbaise I might use that
I can see it is accessible via api too. Awesome